Blazor: displaying the results of execution of a command as they receive
I'm using Blazor Server (.net 8) and I want to display the results of execution of a command as it gets out in the output.
Here's what works but not live (all the results are shown after the execution finishes).
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics

<Button @onclick="ProcessSomething">execute...</Button>

<InputTextArea @bind-Value="output" />


@code{
    string output = "";

    async Task ProcessSomething()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping 8.8.8.8";

        output = "";
        p.OutputDataReceived += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
            
            output += $"{args.Data}\n";
            
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };  
        p.Start();  
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();  
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}

The Console.WriteLine(args.Data); actually prints the results as they come but InputTextArea gets updated only after the execution completely finishes.

The principle problem is the command code is not async.  You're running it on the UI thread, so it blocks that thread until it completes:  The events have no effect because the thread is blocked.
As you're running on Server, you can spin off the command to a Threadpool thread.  This frees the UI to do it's job: responding to events and updating the UI.
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics
@using System.Text

<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@_processing" @onclick="ProcessSomething">execute...</button>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_output</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder _output = new();
    private volatile bool _processing;

    private Task ProcessSomething()
    {
        _output.Clear();
        // The command is blocking
        // so spin the commandoff to a threadpool thread to free up the UI Thread
        Task.Run(RunPingAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async  Task RunPingAsync()
    {
        _processing = true;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping 8.8.8.8";
        p.OutputDataReceived += OnDataReceived;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
        _processing = false;
        // Need to call StateHasChanged to update th button state
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async void OnDataReceived( object? sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
        _output.AppendLine(args.Data);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}

The output now looks like this:


Since Console.WriteLine(args.Data); could actually print the output to the console, I thought that the process is not blocking.
It works perfectly; thanks.

The console in on a different thread.  If you're running a process that starts something and then waits on it, the thread it's running on is blocked.  In your case you were blocking the UI thread.  In my code, I'm blocking a Threadpool thread.
